# How to check number of clients connected to a server

Tags: c, sockets, server

I have created a server in Linux using C language it can serve multiple connections simultaneously. How can I determine the number of clients which are connected to the server and are active at a particular time ?

Comment: You'll have to keep track of it yourself. Increment a counter on every `accept` and decrement it when the connection closes.

Comment: keep a global variable to count the incoming connections. when a connection is received increment it by 1 and when a connection is closed decrement it by 1. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you spawn threads to handle each connection. If that is the case whenever a new connection is made you should add to a counter and decrement whenever a connection is dropped. Very important though, make sure to use Mux's to protect the count variable whenever you go to change/access it.